# помогите найти xpath элемент

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не получается никак сделать клик на эту область

Вот код самого элемента

```
<g class="highcharts-label highcharts-range-input" transform="translate(39,0)">
<rect fill="none" class="highcharts-label-box" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="94" height="21" stroke="#cccccc" stroke-width="1"></rect>
<text x="7.671875" y="14" style="font-size:12px;font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#757575;fill:#757575;">
<tspan>Apr 28, 2013</tspan></text>
</g>
```

Все время ругается на путь, пытался и XPath, и селекторы

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = 'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/#charts')
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-a71zvr2-0"]/svg/g[2]/g[2]/text/tspan')
print(elem)
elem.send_keys("2018-01-16")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.save_screenshot('screencoin.jpg')
driver.quit()
```

в итоге получаю

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "screener.py", line 8, in <module>
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="highcharts-a71zvr2-0"]/svg/g[2]/g[2]/text/tspan')
  File "C:\Users\Milkiweed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 385, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Milkiweed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Milkiweed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Milkiweed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="highcharts-a71zvr2-0"]/svg/g[2]/g[2]/text/tspan"}
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Помогите пожалуйста составить корректный путь к этому элементу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой xpath: `//*[local-name()='rect'][@class='highcharts-label-box']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='text']/*[local-name()='tspan']`

Он вообще вернет 2 элемента, но если вы используете find_element_by_xpath, то вернет тот, что From.